# How to make a sprite jump when the spacebar is pressed?

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to learn how to develop in Swift 4 but I cannot figure out how to check if the space bar is pressed. I have the code for the actual jump but not how to call on it. This is programmed to be used on macOS. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In you `GameScene` add this code snippet:

```
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    guard !event.isARepeat else { return }
    let keyCode: UInt16 = event.keyCode
    print("keyCode = \(keyCode)")
    if keyCode == 49 { // Spacebar
        //Make sprite jump
    }
}
```

the line `guard !event.isARepeat else { return }` is optional, basically it checks  that you aren't holding the key down.